# Torrent client for a NAS

Tags: linux, bittorrent

I'm searching for a torrent client for a NAS (WD My Cloud, 2x650 Mhz Arm, 240 Mb Ram). It should continuously download a file and prioritize first and last piece like [qBittorrent](http://www.qbittorrent.org/) does.

I saw manuals about installing [Transmission](https://www.transmissionbt.com/), it even has a Windows GUI which can connect to other PCs over RPC, but it doesn't support continuous downloading.

Comment: (AFAIC I wouldn't run a torrent client with http://www.peerblock.com/ running at the same time)

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt Could you please elaborate why? I thought they were supposed to be run the same time to block?

Comment: @Slartibartfast good question, I can't recall why I wrote this. I agree with you, I also think they are supposed to be run the same time to block.  2014 Franck is an idiot for not writing the reason in the comment.

Comment: So, installing something on the NAS was a bad idea. I followed a manual, added SID to sources. Somewhen later I run apt upgrade, it updated libc and I got a brick. It lied for a 3 months until I unbricked it. That was faulty manual, typically linux. Just buy some old raspberry pi if you want a home server. For torrents it can be cheaper to lease a seedbox.